# How to reload CoreData's data in main app from the sqlite file updated by app extension?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, core-data

I am in this scenario:

1. My app extension (share extension) insert a new entry using CoreData and the CoreData's SQLite file stored in the `app group`'s shared directory.
2. While switching back to the main app, the main context does not update.

I used `CoreDataStack.shared.mainContext.reset()` but it does not work.

My core stack core (both of my main app and the app extension use this code):

```swift
import CoreData

public class CoreDataStack {

    let appID = "xxx"
    let modelFileName = "xxx"
    let defaultAppGroupID = "xxx"

    public static let shared = CoreDataManager()

    public var mainContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
        return mainPersistentContainer.viewContext
    }
    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let momdURL = bundle.url(forResource: modelFileName, withExtension: "momd")!
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: momdURL)!
    }()

    lazy var mainPersistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: modelFileName, managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel)

        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: defaultAppGroupID)!.appendingPathComponent("\(modelFileName).sqlite"))]

        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (_, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })

        return container
    }()

    public func saveMainContext() {
        let context = mainPersistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

    fileprivate func applicationDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default

        if let url = fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.io.wildcat.InfoFlow") {
            return url
        } else {
            let urls = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
            return urls[0]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try refreshAllObjects()?

Comment: @MartinM, tried in "applicationDidBecomeActive" but it did not work. According to the doc "Refreshes all currently registered objects that are associated with this context". I think the newly added entry has not been 'associated' with the main app's main context.

Comment: Did you ever make any progress? I'm dealing with a similar issue. I've also tried to reload everything in applicationDidBecomeActive, but somehow sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Not sure what the determining factor is.

Comment: Hi @PhilipDeVries, I have answered this question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 2):

I submitted a Code-Level support and here is the answer.

There are two workarounds you can consider:

1. Reload the data from the store when your main app is back to the foreground. After that, reload the data.

```swift
context.reset()
// MARK: Reload the data
// NSFetchedResultsController.performFetch()
// UITableView.reloadData()
```

2. Persistent History Tracking (also enhanced in WWDC 19). Reference: https://stoeffn.de/posts/persistent-history-tracking-in-core-data/